# What is the significance of St. Winifred saying that the Green Knight is someone Gawain knows?

Tags: the-green-knight

In *The Green Knight* (2021), as Gawain was returning St. Winifred's skull, her decapitated head apparated, startling Gawain, causing him to drop her skull.

St. Winifred (or her decapitated head) then said the following to Gawain:

> Now I can see thee.
> And I will strike thee down with every care I have for thee.
> The Green Knight is someone you know.

Why did she say that she will strike Gawain down in that manner? After Gawain left her house, St. Winifred did not reappear in later scenes. I'm wondering what she meant and why she said that to Gawain.

In the film, unlike the source material, it was not made obvious who the Green Knight actually was nor was it revealed that the Green Knight is the Lord of the castle Gawain stayed in. What did St. Winifred mean by "The Green Knight is someone you know"? What is the significance of those lines?

Answer (score 2):

[As explained by Screenrant](https://screenrant.com/gawain-mother-summon-green-knight-why/):

> By summoning the Green Knight and presenting Gawain with a gauntlet of character tests, **Morgan le Fay controls the action from behind the scenes**. For once, Gawain is faced with a test he can't avoid and a duty he can't shirk. While he spends much of the movie failing and hardly living up to the definition of a hero, in the end, he passes the test and takes the first step toward evolving from a wastrel boy to a noble man. **Thanks to his mother's meddling, Gawain finally comes into his own through the course of The Green Knight** and Morgan le Fay's plans for her son, while extreme, pay off.

The Green Knight is basically his mother.

Comment: Related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FIM94dRlKWc